# how can i return a single variable from my vector? c++

Tags: c++, vector, getter

I'm building a music shop application and i have my instruments stored in a vector, for each element in the vector it stores information of the instrument such as price, type of instrument etc I'm trying to build a sale report part of the software and need to return the price of each instrument but i am struggling, i have the input working just fine and when it prints details it prints all of the details but i am struggling getting it to run the whole get price section. I'm sure my code must be wrong can anyone help, any help would be greatly appreciated code below:

```
float getprice(vector<Instrument>& instruments) {
    return this->price;
}

float getpriceinstrument(vector<Instrument>& instruments) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        return instruments[i].getprice(instruments);
    }
}

void printInstrumentdetails(vector<Instrument>& instruments) {
    cout << "Instrument Name: " << name << "\nInstrument make: " << make << "\nInstrument model: " << model << "\nInstrument type: " << type << "\nInstrument price: " << price << endl;
    Instrument::getpriceinstrument(instruments); 
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] which demonstrates how your current attempt fails.

Comment: You  are aware that a loop which contains a `return` will not loop, aren't you?

Comment: `return instruments[i].getprice(instruments);` can you explain why you have this in a loop? When the code hits the return on the first iteration the function is done executing. The rest of the loop will not happen.

Comment: `getprice()` ignores its parameter, for good reason because it seems unneeded.

Comment: `Instrument::getpriceinstrument(instruments);` is odd as well getpriceinstrument() returns a single float which your code threw away. Why do you have this function return a float only to throw it away?

Comment: The call to getpriceinstrumt() returns something which is ignored. I think you should describe in English what you are actually trying to do. Maybe state what output you expect, for a sample vector, for which you should provide a [mre].

Comment: If you post your whole program we will have a better idea of how it hangs together and what the code you show is supposed to do. What you have posted so far really doesnt make much sense

Comment: I agree. None of the implemented functions make sense. They may compile but they have odd functionality by ignoring parameters, throwing away values, printing the wrong values and returning in a loop. You can not program in c++ by guessing. It won't end well.

Comment: There's a lot wrong here... For one, getpriceinstrument will start a loop through the vector of instruments and return at the very first item of the array. As mentioned by @drescherjm, It seems like you were guessing your way through this!

Comment: Do you want a *sequence* of floats representing the price of *each instrument*? In which case the return value `float` is inappropriate